# SQL Server- search is not working for the square bracket

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tblEmpl` which has a column `employeename`. In that employee name column I have a row with a value of `John [Smith]` so I have a query to search the row but it is not selecting any row.

```
select * from tblEmpl 
where EmployeeName like '%John [Smith]%'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE EmployeeName LIKE '%John \[Smith\]%' ESCAPE '\';
```

or

```
WHERE EmployeeName LIKE '%John [[]Smith]%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
select * from tblEmpl where EmployeeName like '%John [[]Smith]%'
```

Comment: Strange but this seems to work for me .I have just edited my sol by giving an extra space between john and bracket .See my result in sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1a58/2

Comment: Yes Praveen, now it is working i guess space was the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select * from tblEmpl where EmployeeName like '%John [[Smith]%'
```

Just replace `[` to `[[`.